# Why my while loop in OCaml doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c, ocaml

I am trying to translate this C code to OCaml code, which should check if the input int is prime number or not. My C code works, but my ocaml code doesn't even run.

```
void is_prime(int pri){
    int a=2;
    int b=poww(a,2);
    while(b<=pri){
       int resu=pri%a;
       if(resu==0) {
            printf("False");
            return 0;
       }
       a++;
       b=poww(a,2);
    }
    printf("True");
}
```

And this is my OCaml code:

```
let is_prime n = 
  let a= ref 2 in
  let b= ref (pow !a 2) in 
  let c= ref true in
  while !b<n do
    let resu= (n mod !a) in
    if resu=0 then c:=false;
    a:=!a+1;
    b:=(pow !a 2);
  done in
  if c=false then false
  else true
;;
```

What I want is an OCaml code takes an int as input and output a boolean. pow in my OCaml code is an existing function pow a b (where a and b are int and output a^b). For some reason, the code doesn't work...

Update: problem solved
New Ocaml code that works:

```
let is_prime n = 
  if n>1 then
    let a= ref 2 in
    let b= ref (pow !a 2) in 
    let c= ref true in

    while !b<n do
    (*ignore (Printf.printf "abc");*)
      let resu= (n mod !a) in
      if resu=0 then c:=false;
      a:=!a+1;
      b:=(pow !a 2);
    done;
    if !c then true
    else false
  else raise Domain
;;
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Your C code doesn't even compile (`return 0` in a function returning `void`).

Comment: `if c=false then false else true` can be simplified to `c`.

Comment: `c=false` looks like a type error to me.

Comment: Why does `b` even exist?

Comment: I saw at least three problems with that. You should start by looking at the error messages and fixing the first one, and then the next, and so on. If you update your post to include the errors you don't understand you might get more useful help.

Comment: hey melpomene, thank you for replying., My C code does work, and i have run it several times.

Comment: @MirageCommander Then either you're ignoring warnings or you're using a non-conforming C compiler. The C standard requires a diagnostic message for a `return` statement with an expression in a function whose return type is `void`. (Note that in the case of gcc you need to use `gcc -pedantic` to get all error messages required by the standard.)

Comment: `if !c then true else false` can be simplified to `!c`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: your C code has `while (b <= pri)`. Your OCaml code has `while !b < n`. The meanings of `<=` in C and `<` in OCaml are different.

Answer (score 0):

As this seems to have been solved, in the interest of thoroughness, this algorithm can be implemented without the need for imperative programming. Instead we can use recursion, and we can define a locally scoped function `aux` to "hide" the initialization and update of `a` and `b`.

```ml
exception Domain_error

let is_prime n =
  if n <= 1 then raise Domain_error;
  let rec aux n a b =
    if b > n then true
    else if n mod a = 0 then false
    else 
      let a' = a + 1 in  
      let b' = int_of_float (float_of_int a' +. 1. ** 2.) in
      aux n a' b'
  in  
  aux n 2 4
```